# Не работает наследование. Где ошибка?

Tags: php

Пример по книге: "Мы можем передать объект BookProduct или CDProduct методу write ( )  класса ShopProductWriter, и все будет работать как надо."

```
<?php

class ShopProduct {

    public $numPages;  // свойство.
    public $playLength;
    public $title;
    public $producerMainName;
    public $producerFirstName;
    public $price;

    function __construct ($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price, $numPages = 0, $playLength = 0) { // конструктор

        $this -> title              = $title; // через $this обращаюсь к свойству этого класса title и присваиваю ему значение (аргумент), которое прилетит в переменную $title, когда вызовется метод конструктора (вызывается при создании нового объекта)
        $this -> producerFirstName  = $firstName;
        $this -> producerMainName   = $mainName;
        $this -> numPages           = $numPages;
        $this -> playLength         = $playLength;
        $this -> price              = $price;

    }

    /* 
        Meтoд  __construct ( ) вызывается,  когда создается объект с помощью оператора new.
        Значения всех перечисленных аргументов передаются конструктору.
        Благодаря конструктору, создание экземпляров класса ShopProduct и определение значений их свойств выполняются в одном операторе.
    */


    function getProducer () { // метод. возвр. имя и фам автора
        return "{$this -> producerFirstName} " .
                "{$this -> producerMainName}";
    }

    function getSummaryLine () { // метод возвращает название альбома (или книги); имя, фамилию автора
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        return $base;
    }

}

                /* Класс CDProduct (дочерний) расширяет возможности класса ShopProduct */

class CDProduct extends ShopProduct {

    function getPlayLength() { // метод. возвращает время звучания
        return $this -> playLength;
    }

    function getSummaryLine () { // метод. возвращает название альбома; имя, фамилию автора и время звучания
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        $base .= ": Время звучания - {$this -> playLength}";
        return $base;
    }

}

                /* Класс BookProduct (дочерний) расширяет возможности класса ShopProduct */

class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {

    function getSummaryLine () {    // метод. возвращает название книги; имя, фамилию автора и количество страниц
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        $base .= ": {$this -> numPages} стр.";
        return $base;
    }
}


class ShopProductWriter {

public function write ($shopProduct) { // метод класса (ему передается обьект $product1 (уточнение, предназначен для работы  с одним типом: ShopProduct) )
    if (! ($shopProduct instanceof CDProduct) && ! ($shopProduct instanceof BookProduct) ) { // если переданный аргумент не относится к типу CDProduct и к типу BookProduct
        die("Передан неверный тип данных");
    }
    $str = "{$shopProduct->title}: " // изменить значение свойства title аргумента прилетевшего в переменную $ShopProduct (не this а $shopProduct->title --- потому, что в методе есть параметр $shopProduct, который принимает прилетевший ему аргумент)
    . $shopProduct -> getProducer()
    ." ({$shopProduct->price})\n ";
    print $str;
    }

}


$product2 = new CDProduct ("Wishmaster", "Группа", "Nightwish", "50 $", null, "70 min");
$product2 -> write($product2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь не к тому классу, метод `write` доступен только в классе `ShopProductWriter`, а вы вызываете его с класса `CDProduct`, вот так должно отработать:

```
$writer = new ShopProductWriter();
$product2 = new CDProduct ("Wishmaster", "Группа", "Nightwish", "50 $", null, "70 min");
$writer->write($product2);
```

Comment: Работает! Спасибо Вам. Теперь буду знать.

Comment: А если сделать класс ShopProductWriter дочерним по отношению к классу ShopProduct, то данная схема уже не работает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что проверка стоит - if (! ($shopProduct instanceof CDProduct) && ! ($shopProduct instanceof BookProduct), по идее можно сделать одну проверку на ShopProduct, они же все его наследуют

Comment: Нет, не работает совсем, т.е. Fatal error...